# Number of ways to express sum.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

> Consider three sets of cards colored Blue, Red and Yellow. Each set has cards numbered $1-10$. The $4$ remaining cards are all indistinguishable cards numbered $0$.
>
> Card numbered $i$ has the value of $2^i$. How many ways are there to choose a group of cards that sums up to $2016$.

I'm having a problem with creating a generating function for this problem, any help would be appreciated.

So far I have $f(x) = (x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)\cdot(1 + x^{2^{1}} + x^{2^{2}} + x^{2^{3}} ... + x^{2^{10}})^3$ but I'm not really sure that's even correct.

Comment: Does it have to be a generating function, or is some other type of solution acceptable?

Comment: It should be done using a generating function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can represent the number of selecting zero up to four indistinguishible cards which have value $2^0=1$ as
\begin{align*}
1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}
\end{align*}

We can represent the number of selecting zero up to three distinguishible cards numbered with value $2^i$ as
\begin{align*}
\left(1+x^{2^i}\right)^3\qquad 1\leq i\leq 10
\end{align*}

The corresponding generating function is
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}\left(1+x^{2^{1}}\right)^3\left(1+x^{2^{2}}\right)^3\left(1+x^{2^{3}}\right)^3\cdots\left(1+x^{2^{10}}\right)^3\\
&\qquad=\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2^{10}-1}x^{2j}\right)^3\\
&\qquad=\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}\left(\frac{1-x^{2^{11}}}{1-x^2}\right)^3\tag{1}
\end{align*}
in accordance with the generating function given by the answer from @RossMillikan.

Next we have to extract the coefficient of $x^{2016}$ from (1). It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ of a series.

> We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{2016}]}&\color{blue}{\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}\left(\frac{1-x^{2^{11}}}{1-x^2}\right)^3}\\
> &=[x^{2016}]\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)^3\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{2016}]-[x^{2011}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-3}{j}(-x^2)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2016}[x^k]-\sum_{k=0}^{2011}[x^k]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{2}x^{2j}\tag{4}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{1008}[x^{2k}]-\sum_{k=0}^{1005}[x^{2k}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{2}x^{2j}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{1008}{2}+\binom{1009}{2}+\binom{1010}{2}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1\,525\,609}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we omit terms in the numerator with powers of  $x^{2^{11}}$ since they do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^{2016}$.
- In (3) we apply $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ and do a geometric and *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$.
- In (5) we skip coefficients of odd powers since they do not contribute.
- In (6) we select the coefficients accordingly.

Comment: I always find your explanations pointed and clear. (+1)

Comment: @user90369: Many thanks for your nice comment and the credit. :-)

Comment: @J.Lastin: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of hints:

With the blue cards, you can make any even number from $0$ to $2^{11}-2$, and you can make it it exactly one way.  (Think binary numbers.)

With the the zero cards, you can make $0$ in $1$ way, $1$ in $4$ ways, $2$ in $6$ ways, etc. if we take account of which zero card we use.  From the statement that the zero cards are indistinguishable, however, I suppose we can make $0,1,2,3,$ or $4$ in one way.

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Honestly I'm struggling with creating the corresponding polynomials for each set of cards because of their changing values.

Answer (score 1):

The blue cards can give you any even value from $0$ through $2046$ in exactly one way, so their generating function is $1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2046}=\frac {1-x^{2048}}{1-x^2}$.  You could also get here by saying the $1$ card has value $2$ so generating function $1+x^2$, the $2$ card has function $1+x^4$ and so on.  Multiply all those together for a given color and you get the above.  Each color can give you the same, so you cube it.  The blanks can give you any value from $0$ to $4$, so their generating function is $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=\frac {1-x^5}{1-x}$ and the overall generating function is 
$$\left(\frac {1-x^5}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac {1-x^{2048}}{1-x^2}\right)^3$$

Comment: Thank you, is there a way for me to get the coefficient for $x^{2016}$ by manipulating this function somehow, or would I have to multiply this and get the result from a computer?

Comment: I don't know of one. I had another approach in mind when I asked if it had to be a generating function.  That approach would be working down from the top.  You can have zero or one cards numbered $10$.  If you have one, you still need to make $992$ and you can have zero or one card numbered $9$.  If you have none, you have to have at least one card numbered $9$ and could have as many as $3$.  Keep working your way down.  The binary will make it not explode in possibilities.

Comment: I tried to ask [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+of+x%5E2016+in+(1-x%5E5)(1-x%5E2048)%5E3%2F(1-x)%2F(1-x%5E2)%5E3).  Its interpretation of the input looks right, but it returns $0$, so there is something wrong

Comment: Each non-negative integer has a unique representation in base 2.  This is a theorem which can be established via generating functions.  Maybe referencing the theorem will suffice to fulfill the requirement that the solution use generating functions.